# How to distinguish multiple devices accessing a servlet on a tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Given a servlet running on a tomcat server, how can one make the servlet distinguish the devices and be used independently from another?

At the moment changes made on one device are visible on another's.

Comment: what do you mean by saying device?

Comment: without knowing what you're trying to do, this is not answerable

Comment: A device like laptop, computer etc.